# Unable to replace \" to " in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace

In my .js have a string

`var jdata ="[{\"name\":\"John\"}]"`

I want to convert it to [{"name":"John"}].

I tried the following but fail

`jdata = jdata.replace("\"","\"")

jdata = jdata.replace("\\"","\"")
jdata = jdata.replace("\\\"","\"")`

What is the right way to replace?

Comment: Do you want an array back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to become an object just do this:

```
JSON.parse(jdata);
```

The result will be `[{"name":"John"}]` objectified.

Otherwise, you already have the job done. If you try to print `"[{\"name\":\"John\"}]"` you will see that has no `\` character as it is an escape character.

Answer (score 5):

`\` is just to use escape the double quotes inside the string (because you use double quote outside).

There is no `\` char in your string actually.

If you want to turn the string to object, then use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you print the string you will see the escape character `\` is not displayed. It is just needed because something enclosed in quotes can't contain quotes that are not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to convert it to a string `[{"name":"John"}]`, you can use regex to do that with:

```
jdata = jdata.replace(/\\\"/,"\"");
```